# Notation of a resampled mean

Tags: bootstrap, resampling, mean, notation

For a work that I have to document, at some point I do N resampling of the initial sample  and generate N means out of them (some kind of bootstrapping). Pretty easy, however I don't know how to write it mathematically, I was thinking of something like:

$\tilde x =  \sum_{k\in\Gamma} x_k$ and then describe $\Gamma$ as a set.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

s... the way I did it in the end was

$\tilde x_l = \sum_{k\in\Gamma_l}x_k$ where $\Gamma_l$ are sets composed of randomly drawn indices. $l=1,...,N$